# Select specific lines in data according to last update

Tags: postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

Barely starting with PostgreSQL I would like to find the correct combination of SELECT to:

select for each Material only the lines in my data that are the most updated.

```
Material_Number  | Last_Chg_Date  | Created_Date
-------------------------------------------------
Mat1             |  23-May-16     |  23-May-14
Mat2             |  23-May-16     |  23-May-14
Mat3             |  23-May-16     |  23-May-14
Mat4             |  23-May-16     |  23-May-12
Mat2             |  24-May-16     |  23-May-14
Mat5             |  25-May-16     |  23-May-13
Mat1             |  26-May-16     |  23-May-14
Mat6             |  26-May-16     |  23-May-14
```

Expected result.

```
Material_Number  | Last_Chg_Date  | Created_Date
-------------------------------------------------
Mat3             |  23-May-16     |  23-May-14
Mat4             |  23-May-16     |  23-May-12
Mat2             |  24-May-16     |  23-May-14
Mat5             |  25-May-16     |  23-May-13
Mat1             |  26-May-16     |  23-May-14
Mat6             |  26-May-16     |  23-May-14
```

the beginning of my code is to select those columns from specific Data:

```
CREATE TABLE `*output_path*` AS
    SELECT
    A.Material_Number,
    A.Last_Chg as Last_Chg_Date,
    A.Created as Created_Date
    FROM `*input_path*` A
```

Can you please help me complete my code.

Comment: For each date you need the last 2 updatedEntries only?

Comment: This question gets asked many times per day here.  Check the duplicate link for several approaches.

Comment: @Arulkumar Hello, I made my question much more specific, hope that helps

Comment: Check out the [Windowed Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) Rank, Dense_Rank, and/or Row_Number.